# Notice: Use of undefined constant Messages -

Tags: php, constants, message

This should work now how it is but it just keeps posting me this error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant Messages

Code:

```
<?php
    if ($user_id>Messages == 1) {
     echo $user_id->Usermessage;
    } elseif($user_id>Messages == 0) {
       echo "No Messages";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what you mean with missing hyphen.

Comment: Ah got it hahahaa stupid error thanks

Answer (score 1):

you missing "-" when your type `$user_id->Usermessage` instead of `$user_id>Usermessage`. So, It should be as follow

```
<?php
    if ($user_id>Messages == 1) {
     echo $user_id->Usermessage;
    } elseif($user_id->Messages == 0) {
       echo "No Messages";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the hyphen `-` in your `elseif` statement. Should be `elseif($user_id->Messages == 0)`